# Missing ip command line tool on macOS

Tags: network

The `ip` program is a multi-purpose network configuration tool that makes use of the full range networking features available in modern Linux kernels.

However, it does not work on Mac:

```
$ ip a
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Switch to Ubuntu,things go well

```
$ ip a
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00 inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo

    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever inet6 ::1/128 scope host
    ...
```

Is there  a substitute tool for it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[This question was asked on Superuser.SE](https://superuser.com/questions/687310/ip-command-in-mac-os-x-terminal/898971)

The accepted solution is to use `brew` to install `iproute2mac`, which adds the ip command.